# function optimization using reinforcement learning

Tags: optimization, python

I'm regular with optimization process, but this time, I would like to optimize a multiobjective function with reinforcement learning, using python.

Of course I already have some testing functions (mathematical or more realistic), but I have no idea on how to proceed with RL.

I would like to compare results with more "traditional" approach.

If you have some tutorials or examples, it would be welcome.

Regards.

Comment: Have you done a literature search?

Comment: of course. But I haven't found examples like finding minimums of a function like himmelblau z=(x**2+y-11)**2+(x+y**2-7)**2  Usually you have a definition step, then boundaries, the run the optimizer. But nothing with RL whereas it looks to be natural because RL is optimization.